# Image as background in menu item

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

As said in the question.

What I currently have:

[image: What I currently have]

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

On each column there would be a background image. I'm going to remove the text and just fill items with images. Is this possible? If yes, do I need different resolutions for background images?

Activity_main_drawer.xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ITEM1"
            android:title="@string/ITEM1"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ITEM2"
            android:title="@string/ITEM2" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ITEM3"
            android:title="@string/ITEM3" />
        </group>
     </menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you are looking to do, you could try add an icon:

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/nav_ITEM1"
   android:icon="@drawable/item1_image"
   android:title="@string/ITEM1" />
```

EDIT / UPDATE: to set the 'background image' of a menu entry, try:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/YOUR_DRAWABLE_HERE". <<<<<<<<<
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

Unfortunately, this sets the same image for each entry - but, it is a good starting point. Will update if I see a way of customising each entry.

LAST UPDATE, This allows you to define a unique background for each entry. Its not perfect, but maybe you can tweak it to work:

1. include 'app' in your xml for your menu:

   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
2. Then, make a simple layout file that has an image:

> ```
> <FrameLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent">
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:src="@drawable/announce"/>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

3. In menu, update the item to point to the layout file you made above

   ```
   <item
       android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
       android:title=""
       app:actionLayout="@layout/test" /> <<<<< HERE
   ```

Source: found some methods and ideas here: https://stablekernel.com/article/using-custom-views-as-menu-items/

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to add an icon. I just want the whole image to fill the item's area.

Comment: @MeryoulSamir Updated! Maybe this will help you in the correct direction

Comment: As you said, it's not perfect but it's a great start to tweaking it. You're a life saver! This community is so great because of people like you. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Really hope it does help getting your end result. If not, maybe you can look into a custom adapter for the menu (if that is even possible for drawer type menus). Wish I could help more, but my drawer menu experience is minimal!